# Chart.js: Can't get a coordinate for value for x axis unless x axis has the exact same value

Tags: javascript, chart.js

What I want to do is to get a position for x axis but I found out I can't get it unless the x axis has the exact same value. But for y axis, I can get position for a value as long as the value is in range of y axis.

Is there a way to get a coordinate for a value in x axis? X axis's labels are numbers and each label has an equal step between the next one.

My current code is like this.

```
<script>
import { Line } from 'vue-chartjs'

export default {
    extends: Line,

    data() {
        return {
            chartdata: {
                labels: [
                    10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100,
                ],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: '',
                        data: [
                            34, 56, 78, 12, 45, 67, 12, 89, 93, 43,
                        ],
                        type: 'line',
                        borderColor: 'red',
                        fill: false,
                        lineTension: 0,
                    }
                ],
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'x',
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            stepSize: 10,
                            suggestedMax: 100,
                        },
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'y',
                        }
                    }],
                }
            }
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        this.addPlugin({
            beforeDraw: (chart) => {
                console.log(chart.scales['y-axis-0'].getPixelForValue(23.56));  // Can get a coordinate in canvas
                console.log(chart.scales['x-axis-0'].getPixelForValue(36.98));  // The coordinate I get is out of canvas
                console.log(chart.scales['x-axis-0'].getPixelForValue(40));  // Can get a coordinate in canvas because label has the same value (40)
            }
        });

        this.renderChart(this.chartdata, this.options);
    }
}
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `data` is an array of numbers, the x-axis is generally a [category](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/category.html#category-cartesian-axis). The points are placed onto the axis using their position in the array, which should also match a value from `labels`.

Yo need to change the x-axis into [linear](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html) type in order to obtain correct values from the function `getPixelForValue`.

1. Don't define `labels`
2. Define the data as an array of [points](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#point) using objects containing `x` and `y` properties each.
3. Add `type: 'linear'` to the `xAxes` option

Please take a look at your amended code and see how it works.

```js
new Chart("chart", {
  type: 'line',
  plugins: [{
    beforeDraw: (chart) => {
      console.log(chart.scales['y-axis-0'].getPixelForValue(23.56));
      console.log(chart.scales['x-axis-0'].getPixelForValue(36.98));
      console.log(chart.scales['x-axis-0'].getPixelForValue(40));
    }
  }],
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: '',
      data: [
        { x: 10, y:34 },
        { x: 20, y:56 },
        { x: 30, y:78 },
        { x: 40, y:12 },
        { x: 50, y:45 },
        { x: 60, y:67 },
        { x: 70, y:12 },
        { x: 80, y:89 },
        { x: 90, y:93 },
        { x: 100, y:43 }],
      type: 'line',
      borderColor: 'red',
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0,
    }],
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{ 
        type: 'linear',
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'x',
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {          
          beginAtZero: true,
          stepSize: 10,
          suggestedMax: 100,
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'y',
        }
      }],
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="200"></canvas>
```